# AWS S3 Url changing dynamically with django statics

Tags: django, amazon-s3, memcached, django-staticfiles, django-compressor

When I am serving static files from AWS S3 using the {%static  %} template I get this type of url:
https://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-2548513.s3.amazonaws.com/css/7aa4edf0c543.css?Signature=lpSpJuyv55JwkjxGKnNVmfn5QKs%3D&Expires=1370880855&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDOQ45S6OQCXGNYQ

Well the signature changes everytime. So when I am using django_storages with offline compression the key for that file is changing everytime because its name is changing so I get the error:
    You have offline compression enabled but key "4c18774209c3d10bb81ec7f466b17e21" is missing from offline manifest. You may need to run "python manage.py compress".

If instead of using the {%static %} template I use a constant URL this error doesn't happens..

Why does the aws s3 has that kind of URL ? Whats the point of the signature and the Expires parameters? I changed my aws s3 configuration to send expires header and cache-control for 1 year, however the expires from the url is just one hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your settings.

It should stop the get params being added to the url.

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Comment: I had the same issue while trying to push all my files to `S3`, and this was the root cause for the above error.