# JQuery script in Django app - 403 error

Tags: jquery, django, amazon-s3

I'm running a Django app locally using Heroku, and s3 for my media + static files. The app includes a mini slide show that cycles through images on command, and is no longer pulling in images, I'm seeing a 403 error as I cycle through the slideshow.

1. The script is embedded in my HTML, not a separate file. This is
   because the I know how to to call the images using `"{{
   listing.image1.url }}"`
2. When I click the next button, I can see it cycling through images
   (although it's showing a broken image in my browser)
3. The s3 setup seems fine - all other media and static files are
4. surfacing properly The script was working fine before I moved to S3
5. I can access the images individually from my HTML

Here is my script, it's my first time writing jquery so it's not well written and the left-scroll is a bit funky:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["{{ listing.image1.url }}", "{{ listing.image2.url }}", "{{ listing.image3.url }}"];
    var indexNum = 1;

    $("#right-scroll").click(function() {
        $("#picture").fadeOut(30, function() {
            $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {indexNum = 0;}
            $("#picture").fadeIn(50);

    $("#left-scroll").click(function() {
        $("#picture").fadeOut(30, function() {
            $("#picture").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum--;
            if (indexNum < 0) {indexNum = 2;}
            $("#picture").fadeIn(50);

        });
        });             
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the relevant HTML section:

```
<div id = "image-gallery">
            <img id = "picture" src ="{{ listing.image1.url }}">
            <img class = "scroll" id = "left-scroll" src="{% static 'left-scroll.jpg' %}">
            <img class = "scroll" id = "right-scroll" src="{% static 'right-scroll.jpg' %}">
</div>
```

Comment: Check the image urls, can you access them individually?

Comment: Yep, there is no problem accessing the images individually from s3. I'll include that point in my question.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? "Not working" is a very vague term. Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @HieuNguyen I've amended the title to be more specific - as I cycle through the images, I'm getting a 403 error in my console.

Comment: I suspect the `imageName` contains the wrong list of URL, could you do `console.log(imageName);` to double check the image URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your settings file:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

This will stop the Expires query parameter being generated.

---

[AWS S3 Url changing dynamically with django statics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027343/aws-s3-url-changing-dynamically-with-django-statics/17027684#17027684)