# Django - static file request from s3 doesn't work

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a django backend that serves it's static files from an amazon s3 bucket.
Everything works fine, and all the static files are getting served.
But now, I tried adding the https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload and it's not able to get the static files needed to display it, even though I used collect static and it's on the server.

The error is:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

and the request is:
http://boxitwebservicebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/js/progress_bar.js

I totally understand why I get it, because id doesn't add the correct AWS key and pass. I just don't understand why it does that to all the other static files, but not this one?

EDIT: For some reason, now I can go to the file, maybe I changed something in the bucket security, but the bar still won't appear. What kind of info can I post for you to help my diagnose the problem? Iv'e been looking at the demo app for hours now and I can't find what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you give an example of a working static file? And don't you need CORS headers set?

Comment: "https://boxitwebservicebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/suit/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?Signature=i4A%2FcvSvVOL7Me2YBTZZkD2pApc%3D&amp;Expires=1386929727&amp;AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI5PVD6A4S2TIZACA"

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct? What permissions are on the bucket and that resource?

Comment: Yeah, Im sure that the url, and I can visit it too, and now the program does as well, but my progress bar is still not working, now without any apparent reason

Comment: So the original question has been solved?

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice have on the url there are a number of parameters.  One of these is `Expires=[TIMESTAMP]`.

After that timestamp has passed the url is no longer valid.  If you remove the parameter and try again it worked fine.

> With query parameters: [link](https://boxitwebservicebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/suit/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?Signature=i4A%2FcvSvVOL7Me2YBTZZkD2pApc%3D&Expires=1386929727&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI5PVD6A4S2TIZACA%22)
>
> Without query parameters: [link](https://boxitwebservicebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/suit/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js)

Add the following to your settings file:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

This will stop the query parameters being generated.

---

[AWS S3 Url changing dynamically with django statics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027343/aws-s3-url-changing-dynamically-with-django-statics/17027684#17027684)